# Failed to assign to property 'System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.Click'

Tags: c#, silverlight, xamlparseexception

Have an interesting situation which I do not understand.

Here's the scenario:

I create a simple Silverlight 5 application.  I place a button control on the main page and create a Click event handler.

XAML is shown below.....

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication6.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="130,43,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

So far so good.

Wire up an event handler in code behind as so ....

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Hi There!!!");
}
```

Compile and run the app. I 'Click' the button and get a nice little message box. Again, so far, so good.

Add a new method (as shown below) to the code behind with the same method name as the button click event handler but with a different signature.

```
private void button1_Click()
{
    MessageBox.Show("This method causes a XamlParseException!");
}
```

Compile and execute the code. Bring up the app and click on the button and I get the following exception:

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Failed to assign to property 'System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.Click'. [Line: 10 Position: 149]
  LineNumber=10
  LinePosition=149
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
       at SilverlightApplication6.MainPage.InitializeComponent()
       at SilverlightApplication6.MainPage..ctor()
       at SilverlightApplication6.App.Application_Startup(Object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
       at MS.Internal.CoreInvokeHandler.InvokeEventHandler(UInt32 typeIndex, Delegate handlerDelegate, Object sender, Object args)
       at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName, UInt32 flags)
  InnerException:
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `void button1_Click()` is not a valid handler for the `Click` event.  `Click` is a `RoutedEventHandler`, which is defined as:

```
public delegate void RoutedEventHandler(
    Object sender,
    RoutedEventArgs e
)
```

Note that you can also use `void button1_Click(object anyName, EventArgs forTheParams)`, it just has to match the delegate closely enough to be converted.

Comment: Correct, it's not a valid handler -- but I'm not trying to use it as such. The mere presence of this code generates the exception.

Comment: Hm...obvious workaround is to rename one of the methods.  Another possible option is to add parameter defaults of null, (`object sender = null, EventArgs e = null`) so that your code can still call `button1_Click()`, and it just has null sender and e params.  If these don't work, an explanation of the relationship between these two overloads would be nice.

Comment: I don't need a work around. That's easy, as you suggested, just rename the method. What I'm curious about is, given the polymorphic nature of C#/.NET/CLR, why the proper method cannot be resolved/determined at run time?

Comment: I have the same problem, but I believe XamlParser is using reflection to search methods with the name of the handler that is set in xaml. If  it finds more than one, throws the exception.

Answer (score 0):

I had the scenario where I linked a button to a method like this...

```
<Button Click="MethodName"..../>
```

I somehow duplicated the method without knowing and as a result I also got this error.
Failed to assign to property 'System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.Click
Hope this can help someone save some time.