# Cryptic exception when C#/WPF project missing NuGet DLL?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm replacing my C++/Wx UI with a C#/WPF UI. The backend is C++. I spent a chunk of yesterday tracking down the following error:

[image]

Turns out the executable was simply missing the tinyxml DLL, which has nothing to do with error given. If this were to happen with my C++/Wx UI, windows would have popped up a runtime dialog saying "tinyxml.dll is missing...", rather than getting the cryptic exception.

I'm new to C# and WPF. Is this a "welcome to C# moment" or is there a workflow change I could make to get a more intuitive errors in future similar situations?

EDIT:

Not a duplicated of [this post about turning on additional exceptions settings](http://XAML%20Parse%20Exception%20-%20xmlns:x=%E2%80%9Chttp://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml%E2%80%9D). I tried the post's suggestion but it still throws the same exception even with all "break when thrown" settings on. Also not a duplicate of [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11106618/failed-to-assign-to-property-system-windows-controls-primitives-buttonbase-clic)

Comment: As mentioned in my EDIT above, not a duplicate question. Please remove banner